# Google chart line chart zoom not working

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've being using the dragToZoom explorer function to add zoom functionality to my line charts.

```
           vAxis:
        {
            baselineColor: '#f5f5f5',
            title: 'No of Users',
            titleTextStyle:
            {
                color: '#00BBF1',
                italic: false,
                fontSize: '20'
            },
            textStyle:
            {
                color: '#f5f5f5'
            },
            viewWindow:
            {
                min: 0,
                format: 'long'
            }
        },
 explorer: { 
        actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
        maxZoomIn: 4.0},

    };
```

But I see zoom is not working.
Am I missing anything?
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImZtS.png)

Kindly help

Comment: are you using string values on the x-axis? explorer only works with continuous axes (such as numbers or dates).